# FBM function for a sparse matrix of 1.3e6x200

Tags: r, foreach, bigstatsr

I need a memory shared sparse matrix of 1.3e6x200. I have tried with bigmemory package but my computer ran out of memory. I have found the function FBM in the package bigstatsr. My code run pretty good with this function for a small example, but I cannot create a matrix higher than 150 000 rows. Any idea could I solve this?
Thank you for your time
[This is the error I have trying to use FBM function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwTBr.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot create a matrix higher than 150 000 rows"? I recently created a matrix 450,000 x 560,000.

Comment: > FBM(nrow=1.3e4,ncol=1.3e6)
Error in getXPtrFBM(.self$bk, .self$nrow, .self$ncol, .self$type) : 
  El volumen para un archivo ha sido alterado externamente, por lo que el archivo abierto ya no es válido. In English: the volume of the file has been changed externally and the open file is not valid

Comment: Have you enough free space on your disk? Have you tried specifying a non-temporary `backingfile`?

Comment: Error in getXPtrFBM(.self$bk, .self$nrow, .self$ncol, .self$type) : 
  The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid. > gc()
            used   (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells   1820217   97.3    3478931  185.8   3052899  163.1
Vcells 210097560 1603.0  361882860 2761.0 301487170 2300.2

Comment: sorry but I don´t understadnd what you mean by trying specifying a non-temporary backingfile.

Comment: There is an argument `backingfile` in `FBM()` to specifiy the location of the backingfile(s). By default, it writes in the `/tmp/` directory. Try é.g. `backingfile = "test"` and it should write a file `test.bk` that contains the data of the FBM.

Comment: `gc()` is showing the amount of RAM used. I'm taking about the amount of DISK space.

Comment: you were right I am almost run out of memory. When I use your function it gives me the same message. How could I save it in an external hard disc, for example in "G:\results\"     FBM(1.3e6,1.3e6,backingfile="G:\results\fbm")

Comment: I never tried with an external disk. You're on Windows? Try e.g. to double the backslashes. Otherwise, you should clean your disk from unused files.

Comment: I am using windows. If I create an R project in my hard disk to run the script and I use FBM(1.3e6,128,backingfile = "test") I can create the file directly in the hard disk. Thank you very much for your help and congratulations for the package